# Как оптимизировать запрос SQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть БД которая собирает информацию и каждую минуту делает запись в БД по 350 записей.

Сейчас строк в таблице 15кк и вес 1.4gb

Делаю запрос по условию поля и за период

```
SELECT * FROM `history_of_global_positioning` WHERE VIN = 'ААААААААААААААА' AND (date_in BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2018-01-30 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-01-30 23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) ORDER BY date_in ASC
```

Результат запроса

> Отображение строк 0 - 24 (1130 всего, Запрос занял 59.3092 сек.)
>   [date_in: 2018-01-30 00:00:03... - 2018-01-30 00:24:03...]

Поставил Ubuntu 17.10 - Развернул PHP 7.2 + MySQL
Железо RAM 2gb, процессор atom 4 ядра 1.7 частоты, SSD 60gb

Собираемся ставить 
Железо RAM 32gb, процессор core i7 4.2 частоты, SSD 256gb + Ubuntu 17.10.1

По началу запрос выполнялся за секунд 15, с ростом базы это время увеличивается. В запросе видно что выборка идёт за сутки, т.е. если я выберу период больше - это будет гиблое дело.

Спасет ли замена железа?
Корректный ли используется запрос?
Что посоветуете?

**Средней расчет записей в год примерно будет 180кк**

Comment: А у вас индекс по полям VIN, date_in (разумеется композитный, из обоих колонок) есть ? И смотрели ли вы план выполнения

Comment: Индекса вообще нет, кроме как как ID записи

Comment: Ну так если нет индекса любой поиск (кроме как по ID) идет полным перебором таблицы. Думаете прочитать с диска и проверить все 1.4gb это быстро ...

Comment: т.е вы мне рекомендуете сделать индексы для VIN, date_in.? Глупый вопрос: Что значит 'композитный'?

Comment: да, индекс для быстрого поиска необходим. композитный - это значит, что это один индекс состоящий сразу из двух колонок. порядок колонок в индексе так же важен, если вы ищите временами vin без указания дат, то vin должен быть первым, если ищете по датам без vin, то даты. и даты на втором месте гораздо предпочтительнее, потому что по ним идет поиск по интервалу.

Comment: Правильный я выполнил запрос?  'ALTER TABLE `history_of_global_positioning` ADD INDEX( `date_in`, `VIN`);'

Comment: Если решили дату все таки сделать первой - то да. но поиск по нему конкретно для этого запроса будет медленнее, чем мог бы быть. потому что сначала будут взяты все записи по интервалу дат, а потом среди них идти поиск по vin (грубо говоря). И обычно все таки индексу задается имя. что бы потом с ним можно было что то сделать и делается это с помощью create index. синтаксис конкретно в sqlite надо просто в документации посмотреть, может и через alter как вы написали работает

Comment: Спасибо большое!